# What is the style for text in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, styling

I have a subclass of AlertDialog that I need text in, but I can't figure out how the dialog styles its text. On Jellybean, it is white on black, and on Froyo, it is white on blue (In other words, I want to find a function that gives me white on both systems, but is also correct on other themes). I've tried the following:

- `TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle` and `TextAppearance.Small` (also `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"`) gives white on Jellybean and black on Froyo
- `TextAppearance.Small.Inverse` or `textColorPrimaryInverse` gives black on Jellybean and white on Froyo
- I can't figure out how `Theme.Dialog.Alert` gives a text color

How does `AlertDialog` do it? Here is the [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#L498) file I am basing my guesses from.

**Edit:** The comment on [this blog](http://blog.andromo.com/2011/fixing-text-colours-on-an-alertdialog-when-using-theme-light/#comment-9893) is related to my difficulty. She has the problem of white-on-white with the fix proposed in the blog (use `textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly`); I have black-on-black in Jellybean. Is this actually a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: can;t you just create `Dialog` with custom theme extending default dialog and setting own background with text color?

Comment: @deadfish The class already inherits `AlertDialog`, and it's not practical to change that at this point. I imagine I could still do what you are saying, although I'm not certain about the specifics of that process.

Comment: @deadfish Correction: my class is a subclass of `DialogPreference`, which creates an `AlertDialog` internally.